# Routing error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have the following in my view (index.html.erb) code:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <%= link_to (@project) do %>
      <div id="tombstone">
         ...Some HTML here...
      </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The goal is to have each project's synopsis displayed inside the tombstone DIV and have the entire DIV act as the link to the project's details page (show.html.erb).

My Controller has the following:

```
def show
   @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

and the routes has the following:

```
resources :projects do
   ...
   resources :updates
end
```

The `@project` in the `<%= link_to %>` points back to the projects (index.html.erb) page, not to the project details page (show.html.erb) that the controller defines.  I can only guess that the ID parameter isn't getting passed, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: `link_to project_path(project) do` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to(project) do %> # not @project
```

Technically you've been sent to index because @project probably new record. @project == Project.new, so link_to(Project.new) with GET request renders path to index action.

Comment: Heh, Noob error.  But then again, I am a Noob.  (6 weeks on Rails and loving it!)